# Ember change normalizeResponse based on queried model

Tags: serialization, ember.js, normalization

I'm using a second datastore with my Ember app, so I can communicate with a separate external API. I have no control over this API.

With a `DS.JSONSerializer` I can add some missing properties like `id`:

```
normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    if (requestType == 'query') {
        payload.forEach(function(el, index) {
            payload[index].id = index
        })
    }
```

Now I can do some different tricks for each different `requestType`. But every response is parsed. Now sometimes a response from one request needs to be parsed differently.

So what I am trying to do is change the `normalizeResponse` functionality for each *different* request path (mapped to a fake model using `pathForType` in an **adapter** for this store). But the argument `store` is always the same (obviously) and the argument `promaryModelClass` is always *"unknown mixin"* - not sure if this can be any help.

How can I find what model was requested? With this information I could do a `switch()` in `normalizeResponse`.

Is there a different way to achieve my goal that does not require me to make a separate adapter for every path/model?

There are [over a dozen normalize functions available](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.JSONSerializer). Something should work for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You can create separate serializer/adapter for model (name it the same as model and ember will use it for that model).

Comment: Good advise, although I knew this already. The method is very verbose. I'm specifically looking for a way to do this in my one adapter or serializer that works fine for everything else.

Comment: Docs say that `primaryModelClass` is a `DS.Model` which means  `primaryModelClass.modelName` should return model name. And I just tested it on my project and it contains model name.

Comment: @GennadyDogaev this works! This is exactly what I am looking for. I tried `primartModelClass.name` which is always `Class`. You put two and two together. Turn this into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`primaryModelClass.modelName`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.Model/properties/modelName?anchor=modelName).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a great example of a use case of not using ember data.

Assuming that you have models A,B,C that are all working great with ember data, leave those alone.

I'd create a separate service and make raw requests to that different endpoint. So you'd replace `this.store.query('thing', {args})` with a separate service that uses ember-ajax (or ember-fetch or whatever). If you need, you can use that service to hold the data that you need (Ember-data is just a service anyway) or you can create models and push them into the store manually.

Without knowing more about your exact situation, hard to give a specific code/advice, but I'd just avoid this problem and write your own custom service.

Comment: I am actually using a `service`/`serializer`/`adapter` combo to implement a custom "datastore", separate from the default data store. I'm specifically looking for a way to normalize every response, depending on what the actual request path/model was. As @GennadyDogaev pointed out, this can be done with a separate adapter for every model, but I'm looking for a way to do this using normalization in a single file. There are over a dozen normalization functions available. Something should work, right?